# How to change the z-index value of image on click of a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular, css

Expectation : I would like to select the image and the click the button then the selected image should appear front and other images should appear behind the seleted image .

I have found the similar solution in stackoverlfow where on clicking the image itself , z-index of that image is changed and for othe rimages ,z-index is set to 0 .

```js
let images = document.getElementsByClassName('imgClass');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(images, (img) => {
    img.addEventListener('click', function () {
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(images, (img) => img.style.zIndex = 0);
        this.style.zIndex = 100;
    });
});
```

But I want to change the z-index of selected image on click of a button and all the other unselected images should have z-index set to 0.

Below is my code:

Here addOn.level is the z-index value which sets the value of z-index for the selected image to 100 but when i select the other image , the z-index value of previous image is still set to 100 .

HTML :

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction(){  
        if (angular.isDefined(activePortalComponent)) {
            var _viewModel = activePortalComponent.viewModel;
            var addOn = _viewModel.actSlideShow
                            .children[ _viewModel.currentSlide ]
                            .children[ _viewModel.selectedAddon ];

            addOn.level = "100";  
        }
    }
```

Function which identifies the selected element : 
$scope.selectElement = function (index) { 
$scope.viewModel.selectedAddon = index; $scope.viewModel.currentAddOnCommand.command.params.currentA‌​ddOn = index; $scope.execute($scope.viewModel.currentAddOnCommand.command)‌​;

Comment: i am not sure about this but render2 might be of help here

Comment: ho do you identify if an image is selected?

Comment: I have included the function which identifies the selected element in the code .